# Extract rows in a data frame based on condition of a column in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
port_id           report_dt       market_val
--------          ---------
100               1200            300
100               1200            500
100               1200            270

100               1300            320
100               1300            490
100               1300            310

101               1200            440
101               1200            320

102               1300            420
102               1300            425
```

Each row is a stock in the portfolio specified by port_id for each reporting date. One port_id can be reported once or more than once
For example: port_id = 100 are reported twice, the first three rows are 3 stocks in port_id = 100 for the date 1200. And the next three rows are 3 stocks in port_id = 100, too; but for the date 1300.
However port_id = 102 and 103 are reported only once.

I want to keep all MOST RECENTLY REPORTED stocks for each port_id, which should look like:

```
port_id           report_dt       market_val
--------          ---------
100               1300            320
100               1300            490
100               1300            310

101               1200            440
101               1200            320

102               1300            420
102               1300            425
```

Please tell me how can I do that. Thanks

Comment: ok, I did. the result should look like the second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
df[df$report_dt == max(df$report_dt), ]
#  port_id report_dt market_val
#4     100      1300        320
#5     100      1300        490
#6     100      1300       3100
```

**Update**
From your updated edit. Here's a way:

```
splt <- lapply(split(df, df$port_id), function(x) x[x$report_dt == max(x$report_dt),])
newdf <- do.call(rbind, splt)
rownames(newdf) <- NULL
newdf
#   port_id report_dt market_val
# 1     100      1300        320
# 2     100      1300        490
# 3     100      1300       3100
# 4     101      1200        440
# 5     101      1200        320
# 6     102      1300        420
# 7     120      1300        425
```

Note: I hate that I had to split, apply, combine so literally. But the SAC functions weren't working for me. I'd love to optimize if anyone has ideas.

Comment: Thanks. But in my df, there are more than one port_id, each port_id can be reported once or more than once. For each port_id, I want to keep only rows which are most recently reported.

Comment: ok, if you would like an answer for situations that you haven't provided please consider expanding your question with the relevant information.

Comment: I'm sorry about my lack of clarity. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `dplyr` approach.

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, port_id == 100, report_dt == 1300)
  port_id report_dt market_val
1     100      1300        320
2     100      1300        490
3     100      1300       3100
```